# iOS 6 Autolayout not resizing properly

Tags: ios, ios6, footer, autolayout

So all I'm trying to do is put an imageview at the foot of the screen. Before iOS6 autolayout I could just hit the bottom "I" and it would hold it to the bottom and push it up if the screen got short (i.e. if the screen size went from 568 to 480 points tall). But now I have been trying to add a bottom spacing to Superview at 0 but I can't seem to do anything to get rid of the the top spacing constraint to stop messing me up. If I convert the top spacing to a user constraint and then delete it then (thinking that the vertical constraint would be handled by the bottom spacing) but it auto re-creates that contraint...  any ideas?

[image: ScreenShot]

**Update** It seems it was due to the fact that I was having it be a subview of a scrollview (was going to use it for scrolling horizontally, not vertically). Anyone know why it wont let me do that? Seems like you should still be able to constraint to the bottom of a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Button's constraints are somehow wrong. Having the height, width, bottom distance and horizontal centering should be enough to define its position. Try deleting the button and centering the image view on the super view instead, and see if tha allows you to delete that top constraint.

Comment: it seems that it was because of the fact that it was a subview of a scrollview (Was trying to scroll horizontally not vertically)... sigh... guess I'm animating all of that by hand. Thanks anyways!